# Selecting a fixed amount of rows n times in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm relatively new to R. I have an xts dataset of 5 columns and around 400 rows.
I'm trying to build a function to select the first 100 rows, then row 2-101, then 3-102 etc, preferably also storing the result in a new object.
Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` for a rolling split

```
n <- 100
lapply(1:(nrow(df) - n), function(x) df[x:(x + n), ])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rollapply`

```
library(zoo)
lapply(asplit(rollapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), width = 100, FUN = I), 2), 
         function(i) df[i, ])
```